# Get rid of `disabling jobserver mode` warning?

Tags: makefile, cmake, gnu-make

In my `CMakeLists.txt` file, I use a custom command

```
add_custom_command(TARGET my_target
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} 
        COMMAND make -j`nproc`
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

because I want to rerun make after building `my_target`. It shows this warning -- `warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.` Everything works fine but how can I remove this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `-j` option from your make invocation in your CMake file and the warning will go away.  By forcing this option you're essentially creating an entirely new jobserver domain, separate from the already-existing one (so if you ran `make -j$(nproc)` from the command line, then ran this, you would have `$(nproc)*2` jobs running).

Comment: If I change `COMMAND make -j`nproc`` to `COMMAND make`, I get this warning -- `make[3]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.` How to fix this one?

Comment: The warning got removed by changing it to `COMMAND +make`. I am accepting the answer, Thanks.

Comment: Note that this solution will fail if you ever use a different generator than Makefiles (e.g., if you try to use Ninja or something else).  However, if you're happy with that you might try using: `COMMAND \$(MAKE)` instead (include the backslash so the dollar sign is not interpreted by cmake).  That might be enough to let the sub-make run with the same jobserver as the parent.  Again, though: will fail for any non-makefile generator.

Comment: Using `+make` probably leads to a rule in the cmake generated Makefile's that looks like:  rule: deps\n\t+make  and where the '+' is interpreted by make. So also that will fail when you use a generator different than Makefiles, right?